# I'm having trouble connecting to the Google analytics 4 API using php

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

However, whenever I make a request I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

1. I created a service account on Google Cloud Platform and generated an API key;
2. I added the client_email in the Google analytics count that I want to retrieve the data (with admin permission);
3. I configured the Google API client library for PHP. `google/apiclient`;

[I used the following tutorial from google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php?hl=pt-br)
Here is a snippet of the code I used:

```
    public function __construct() {
        $analytics = $this->initializeAnalytics();
        $this->getReport($analytics);

    }

    function initializeAnalytics()
    {

        // Use the developers console and download your service account
        // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
        // change the key file location if necessary.
        $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';

        // Create and configure a new client object.
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
        $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
        $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
        $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

        return $analytics;
    }

    function getReport($analytics) {

        // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
        $VIEW_ID = "here I put my id";

        // Create the DateRange object.
        $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
        $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
        $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

        // Create the Metrics object.
        $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
        $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
        $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

        // Create the ReportRequest object.
        $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
        $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
        $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
        $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

        $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
        $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
        return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
    }
```